# How can I install an SSL certificate using Amazon Certificate Manager to a VirtualHost?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, https, elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk and a t2.micro instance to host a few of my websites. For one of the websites specifically, I want to enable https. How do I go about doing this?

I have each domain pointing toward a different folder in the instance. I just want one of them to be able to use https. I figure that ACM would be the easiest way of doing this, from what I've read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACM certificates neither require nor support installation directly on the instances serving the web site.  They are installed on the upstream infrastructure (CloudFront or ELB, including the balancer for Elastic Beanstalk).  Deploying them is straightforward because you don't have to do, really, anything to make it work, though you'll need some smaller changes if, for example, you want to force browsers to HTTP.

As long as your Elastic Beanstalk deployment us in us-east-1 (Northern Virginia), you can attach an ACM cert to your stack with minimal changes.  The connection between the balancer and your instancr is not encrypted, but the connection between the browser and the balancer is -- this seems to be a generally-acccepted practice, except in high-security or compliance-constrained environments, because the unencrypted traffic is not on a network that is believed to be susceptible to sniffing.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html for deploying HTTPS in general and using ACM certificates specifically, with EB.

Comment: Thanks so much. So once I deploy this SSL certificate, I can just use https or http on each of the VirtualHosts? Is there any additional configuration I need to do for my vhosts.conf file? Or .htaccess?